# Test case failing with undefined property passed over props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been learning react for a while and have been working on creating a pet project. My friend created a test case which tests out some notification message from a method. This method in turn will use a constant from another class.

Below notification component utilizes a set of props(especially the partner props) passed over from routes.js.

```
class Notification extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            orientation: "ltr",
            services: {
                "applications": [],
                "eta": "",
                "start": ""
            },
            statuses: {},
            locale_date: new Date(),
            modal: {
                open: false,
                header: null,
                desription: null
            },
            // This shouldn't be hardcoded but there are issues with passing this in as a prop in Routes.js
            partner: props.partner
        }

        this.refreshEndpoints();
    }

    refreshEndpoints = () => {
        const ref = this;

        axios
            .get(this.state.partner.get_device_status_url)
            .then(response => {
                var statuses = response.data;

                if((typeof statuses) !== 'object') return false;

                ref.setState({
                    statuses: statuses
                });

            }).catch(error => {

            });
    }

    handleCreateNotification = () => {
        const ref = this;

        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(ref.state.services)
        };

        adalApiFetch(fetch, this.state.partner.get_endpoint_notifications_banner, options)
        .then(response => {
            ref.setState({
                modal: {
                    open: true,
                    header: "Success",
                    description: "Successfully Created Notification"
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            ref.setState({
                modal: {
                    open: true,
                    header: "Error",
                    description: "Failed to Create Notification"
                }
            });
        });
    }

    handleDeleteNotification = () => {
        const ref = this;

        const options = {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(ref.state.services)
        };

        adalApiFetch(fetch, this.state.partner.get_endpoint_notifications_banner, options)
        .then(response => {
            ref.setState({
                modal: {
                    open: true,
                    header: "Success",
                    description: "Successfully Deleted Notification"
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            ref.setState({
                modal: {
                    open: true,
                    header: "Error",
                    description: "Failed to Delete Notification"
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

In routes.js I have route for calling out the above component which passes the props for partner.

```
<ProtectedNotificationPage orientation={orientation} partner={PartnerOne}/>
```

ParnerOne.js:

```
export const get_endpoint_notifications_banner = "<some url>"
export const get_device_status_url = "<some url>"

<class components>
```

I want to utilize the above const in notification component. And I was able to accomplish that using props.partner inside the state method.

But below test case is failing due to undefined property which is strange. But the notification functionality completely works fine. clearing and adding notification has no issues.

```
describe('Notification component', () => {
    it('handleCreateNotification - Success', async () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Notification />);

        await wrapper.instance().handleCreateNotification();

        expect(wrapper.state().modal).toEqual(
            {
                open: true,
                header: "Success",
                description: "Successfully Created Notification"
            }
        );
    });

    it('handleDeleteNotification', async () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Notification />);

        await wrapper.instance().handleDeleteNotification();

        expect(wrapper.state().modal).toEqual(
            {
                open: true,
                header: "Success",
                description: "Successfully Deleted Notification"
            }
        );
    });
```

I apologize for my lack of knowledge.. But this is something I couldn't figure out over tutorials/blogs. And I really appreciate if anyone able to point out the issue or reference for fixing this.

I tried utilizing bind across methods, which is something I thought might fix. But didn't workout. Apart from that I also tried accessing the props directly

like this.props.partner.get_device_status_url.. And still test case were failing.

Answer (score 0):

#### I would suggest the following:

Importing into `Notification.js`:

`const { get_endpoint_notifications_banner, get_device_status_url } = '<path_to_file>'`.

You can now access these variables directly inside `Notification.js`.

Comment: Thanks!! But I want to use it like that. Because in future if I want to add another component like PartnerTwo I can reuse them in the existing notification setup.

Comment: You could try importing everything from `PartnerOne.js`, like `import * as PartnerOne from './PartnerOne.js`. I guess you would then have to reference the component as `PartnerOne.default`.

Comment: Thanks mattemyo. I found out the issue. Adding a mock object for partner props fixed that. Thank you for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Test case was having some issue. When I passed the partner one as props to my test case. It fixed the issue. It was looking for missing props